# Change Azure Subscription

Tags: azure

How would I change the Azure subscription that a particular resource is associated with? I'm trying to move some things from my MSDN account to a pay as you go account. I'm hoping to avoid having to copy all my data over to new SQL resources and redeploy everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently Azure announced such feature where you could move at least some resources of your Azure Subscription to another resource group in the same Subscription or another Subscription all together. Please read this post from Azure team for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/ and see if this would work for you.

If this doesn't work for you, you may want to reach out to Azure Support and see if they can do partial transfer of resources across subscriptions.

Last resort obviously (and as you mentioned) is to move the resources yourself.